At what altitude will an explosive depressurization cause structural failure?
Rapid depressurization at high altitude is generally a very, very bad thing, because the aircraft will quickly loose altitude and may suffer damage to vital areas. There are three forms of depressurization: gradual depressurization, rapid depressurization, and explosive depressurization. As the name suggests, explosive depressurization is the most serious of all, and can cause various issues, ranging from minor damages like a blown-out door and someone sucked out (see Southwest Airlines Flight 1380), to complete structural failure and/or loss of control and subsequent crash (see Turkish Airlines Flight 981). However, my question is, at what altitude will an explosive depressurization cause structural failure? I reasoned that the higher the aircraft, the higher the pressure difference between the surrounding air and the inside of the aircraft before the depressurization, and thus the more severe the depressurization event. However, I may be wrong, so please tell me if my assumption is incorrect. My question can be summarized as follows:

Why do some explosive depressurization cause structural failure while others just cause minor damage?
is the above because of altitude (i.e., the higher the altitude, the more severe the damage.)?
if it is because of altitude, then at (approximately) what altitude will an explosive depressurization event cause structural failure?

I appreciate any explanation. Thanks in advance!

"because the aircraft will quickly loose altitude" -> that is a common misconception from Hollywood movies. The aircraft can maintain altitude after an explosive depressurization just fine (except when control cables are damaged, like in THY981). It's just bad for the people on board, so the pilots typically initiate an emergency descent.

the title makes no sense, altitude is orthogonal to the cause of structural failure.

I'm downvoting, because like your other questions, you make completely unfounded assertions.

@Bianfable Thanks for pointing out, so explosive depressurization does not cause a loss of altitude. It's just because of the emergency decent made by the pilots, which is part of the standard procedure of reacting to an explosive depressurization. Thanks, I learned something new here.

@Federico I'm not so sure if the altitude is connected with structural failure, and stated so in my post. So, if you think they are not related, you can tell me in comments (as you did), or post an answer stating that, rather than downvoting. Anyways, can you please suggest a title that you think makes more sense and better? Thanks!

@MichaelHall What assumption do you think is "completely unfounded"? Is it also the assumption of the higher the altitude, the more severe the damage thing?  Can you please state which assumption you think is incorrect so I can possibly change it? Also, you can just tell me that my assumption is incorrect and I'll change it, no need to downvote. Additionally, which of my other posts that you downvoted because of unfounded assumptions? Please tell me, so I can improve them as well. Thanks.

"Rapid depressurization at high altitude is generally a very, very bad thing, because the aircraft will quickly loose altitude and may suffer damage to vital areas." and "the slightest movement of an elephant that weighs more than 3 tons would most likely cause the aircraft to roll, pitch, or drop, and may even break the fuselage if the elephant's force is great enough." are the two statements that immediately come to mind.

I think you simply have to write your question without much more straightforward without much blah blah around it

@sophit Can you please explain a bit more? What does "without much more straightforward without much blah blah around it" mean? What parts do you think I can remove? Thanks :)

Oh, this question is unexpectedly extremely ill-received. Can anyone please tell me how to improve to make this post useful to future readers? Also, I can't delete this question now, and I would like to stop the downvoting. Are there any suggestions? What part(s) should I delete, what should I clarify more, and what should I reword/rephrase? I'll appreciate any help. Thanks a lot in advance!

You have it backwards:  Explosive decompression doesn't cause structural failure, structural failure causes explosive decompression.
The pressure differential is greater at high altitude which increases the probability and severity of such an event, but is otherwise irrelevant.
